# How to save foreign key in django Model Form

Tags: python, django

I have two models and one form and one formsets so Formsets contains foreign of form and I want to save add id to formsets when saving both the forms and formsets.

model.py

```
class fmodel(models.Model):
   name=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

class smodel(models.Model):
   desc=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
   n=models.ForeignKey(fmodel,null=True,blank=True,related_name='somemodel')
```

forms.py

```
class fmodelForm(forms.ModelForm):
   name=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
         model=fmodel
         fields=['name']

smodelFormset=modelformset_factory(
  smodel,
  fields=('desc',),
  extra=1,
  widgets={
      'desc':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'u-form'})
  }
)
```

template

```
<div>
   <form role="form" action="//" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">{% csrf_token %}
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                <label> name : </label>
                  {{form.name}}
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                 {{ form1.management_form }}
                 {% for f in form1 %}
                <label> desc : </label>
                  {{f.desc}}
                 {% endfor %}
          </div>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
   </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
form=fmodelForm(request.POST or None)
formset = smodelFormset(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
if formset.is_valid():
   forms=formset.save(commit=False)
   for f in forms:
    #here I want to add id of previously added form
    f.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `form.save()` returns the instance it has saved. We can then iterate over the forms, and for each form, set the `.foreign_key`of the `f.instance` to that instance:

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for obj in instances:
        obj.foreign_key = instance
        obj.save()
```

You probably first want to validate both the `form` and the `formset`. Since if one of the two is invalid. It might be better not to save any data at all.

Comment: For some reason when I write condition "if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():" the formsets is not saving.

Comment: @SharathNayak: hold on, `formset.save()` will give you the object instances, not the forms. So you iterate over `obj`s, see edit.

Comment: @SharathNayak: did you exclude the `foreign_key` out of the form that is wrapped in your `formset` forms? You should, of course, not validate that field, since at that time it is not yet set.

Comment: I excluded the "foreign key" out of the form and I understood your answer but for some reason if I add that "if condition" formset is not saving the values.

Comment: @SharathNayak: so `formset.is_valid()` is `False`? Can you render/print the errors that this formset generates?

Comment: It's saying" those html tags are empty"

Comment: @SharathNayak:did you create the `formset` with `request.POST` (or `request.GET`) as data source?

Comment: Actually there is one "form" tag and it contains both form and formset and yes i added request.POST

Comment: @SharathNayak: can you edit your question with the relevant parts of the template and view?

Comment: Yes, I will do that

Comment: I just added all the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Feeling so dumb now after solving my own question.

so here is the answer:

views.py

```
form=fmodelForm(request.POST or None)
formset = smodelFormset(request.POST or None)

#Just add 
if request.method == 'POST':
   if form.is_valid() and if formset.is_valid():
      instance=form.save()
      forms=formset.save(commit=False)
      for f in forms:
       f.foreignkey=instance.id
       f.save()
```